# Verifying method calls on lambda with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, lambda, junit, mockito

I'm trying to verify and capture the arguments of some method calls within a lambda expression as so:

```
public Optional<UserDetails> findOne(String userName) {
    String selectStatement =
        "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userName = :userName;";

    return jdbi.withHandle(handle -> handle
            .createQuery(selectStatement)
            .bind("userName", userName)
            .map(new UserDetailsMapper())
            .findOne());
  }
```

`jdbi.withHandle()` takes an argument of `HandleCallBack`, which looks like this:

```
public interface HandleCallback<T, X extends Exception> {
  T withHandle(Handle handle) throws X;
}
```

For example, I want to verify that `.bind()` has been called with `"userName"` and the passed in `userName` argument string from my `findOne` method.

It does feel like I'm unit testing the Jdbi class rather than my own class, but I feel like the arguments to `.createQuery()` `.bind()` and `.map()` should be tested as these could be accidentally changed by a developer.

The approach I've currently taken is to create an in-memory database and test what is actually being returned, but this feels more like an integration test than a unit test. I also don't really care what is actually returned by the Jdbi `.withHandle()` method, as I would essentially be testing a library at that point.

My understanding is that I should be unit testing the arguments passed to `.withHandle()` (in this case, a lambda expression), which is what I'm trying to do here.

The closest I got was by moving the logic into a method reference, but that won't work as `userName` is passed into my `findOne()` method and then used inside the lambda.

I've also played around with Mockito's `doAnswer` to no avail.

I can only think of creating a new class with helper methods to return `userName`, `selectStatement`, etc, and verify that they are called, but it feels unnecessary and will be added simply to provide testability.

Comment: I'd consider [acolyte jdbc driver](https://github.com/cchantep/acolyte). Maybe with [jsqlparser](https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser) for some specific corrner cases.

Comment: You shouldn't to test against the implementation which makes the test coupled with the implementation code. In other words, you must change the test code when  parameter `userName` was changed in production code by other users, which result in the test is overly depends on the implemenation.

Answer (score 0):

The lambda expression is part of the implementation of the findOne method. So, you should test it as part of testing findOne. But it is not executed when doing the call to findOne. So, to be able to test it, executing findOne and doing verifications and assertions on that will not be enough.

I would mock jdbi and then do a verification on the call with an ArgumentCaptor that captures the lambda function. Then you can pass that lambda function as a parameter to a test method which tests the lambda function. That method can look the same as any other test method except that it can never be ran as a separate test case.

In this case, I think one such test method will be enough. But sometimes when testing lambda function, you might need to create and call several test methods to test the captured lambda function with different input values.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have shown is dominated by interactions with the various classes of jdbi.  Such code should rather be tested with integration testing than with unit-testing because there are many potential bugs in the interactions: Are you calling the right functions in the proper order, with the arguments in the right order and of the right format, and are the results of each call as you expect them to be (including possible exceptions)?

For identifying those potential bugs integration testing is the proper approach: A mocked environment will not help you find these bugs.  You would implement the mocks according to your own understanding (that is, also according to your own potential misunderstanding).

As an example, consider your stated goal that you would like to test that `bind` was called with `"userName"` and the `userName` argument: If you mock `bind`, then your mocked `bind` would test that `"userName"` comes as first argument, and the content of `userName` as second.  But, that does not tell you much, because your assumed order could be wrong, or because `"userName"` might still differ from the variable name in the `SELECT` statement, such that the real `bind` would fail etc.

That said, I agree with Stefan Mondelaers' point that the lambda expression belongs to the `findOne` method and should be tested together with it - it's just that I would test it directly with integration testing and not put any effort in unit-testing in this particular case.